# Laravel 5 Query builder LOGICAL NOT

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I need to port this **MYSQL** query to **Laravel 5.2 Query Builder** and I'm not figuring out how to successfully implement the **Logical NOT** part:

```
SET @in='2017-06-01', @out='2017-06-01';

SELECT
  rooms.id,
  rooms.name,
  reservations.check_in,
  reservations.check_out,
  reservations.room_id
FROM
  rooms
  LEFT JOIN
  reservations
    ON rooms.id = reservations.room_id AND
    NOT (
        (reservations.check_in < @in AND reservations.check_out < @in)
        OR
        (reservations.check_in > @out AND reservations.check_out > @out)
    )
WHERE reservations.room_id IS NULL
```

I'm trying to use a **Query Builder's raw query** but it's not working, I get a **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::whereNull()** error

```
$free_rooms = Room
    ::select('rooms.id', 'rooms.name')
    ->leftJoin('reservations', 'rooms.id', '=', 'reservations.room_id') AND
            DB::raw("

            NOT (
                (reservations.check_in < $request->check_in AND reservations.check_out < $request->check_in) 
                OR 
                (reservations.check_in > $request->check_out AND reservations.check_out > $request->check_out)
            )

            ")
    ->whereNull('reservations.room_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: If your query is too complex for the query builder, you can always use [hydrateRaw()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hydrateRaw). `Room::hydrateRaw($rawQuery, $bindings)`

Comment: I'm getting a **SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number** error now, here a paste of how my code looks: https://pastebin.com/mQsjMVqV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:**

```
    ->leftJoin('reservations', 'rooms.id', '=', 'reservations.room_id') AND
```

That `AND` is parsed as a PHP operator - not SQL!

and

```
->whereNull('reservations.room_id')
```

is chained on the result of `DB::raw(...)` and causes the exception.

**Second:** your join condition can be simplified to

```
ON  rooms.id = reservations.room_id
AND reservations.check_out >= @in
AND reservations.check_in  <= @out
```

**Third:** If a big part of your query is "raw" it's better not to use the query builder at all. User `hydrateRaw()` instead

```
$rawQuery = "
    SELECT
      rooms.id,
      rooms.name
    FROM
      rooms
      LEFT JOIN
      reservations
        ON  rooms.id = reservations.room_id
        AND reservations.check_out >= :check_in
        AND reservations.check_in  <= :check_out
    WHERE reservations.room_id IS NULL
";

$bindings = [
    'check_in'  => $request->check_in,
    'check_out' => $request->check_out
];

$free_rooms = Room::hydrateRaw($rawQuery, $bindings);
```

Note that I have just simplified your condition keeping the logic. But usually a customer can check in on the same day (in the afternoon) when another one checks out (in the morning). So the condition should be

```
        AND reservations.check_out > :check_in
        AND reservations.check_in  < :check_out
```